# Python script not able to read user input when run remotely

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh

I am trying to remotely execute a simple python script userinfo.py present in remotehost.

Below is sourcecode of userinfo.py [ using Python 2.7.10 ]

```
#############
print "Userinfo :"
name=raw_input("Enter your name")
age=raw_input("Enter your age")
print "Name"+name+"\nAge"+age
#############
```

But script is working abnormally when run remotely.

```
[user@localhost]# ssh remotehost python /home/userinfo.py
```

> Userinfo :
>
> Enter your nameEnter your ageName
>
> Age
>
> [user@localhost]#
>
> Execution summary ::

During execution, it doesn't print anything, it directly waits for user input and I just pressed Enter key it will display output as above.

Would like to know why it is not behaving as expected when raw_input is used.

When values are passed as arguments, it works fine.

> [user@localhost]# ssh remotehost python userinfo.py xyz 20
>
> Userinfo :
>
> Name xyz
>
> Age 20
>
> [user@localhost]#

below is changed code.

```
###########
import sys
print "Userinfo :"
name=sys.argv[1]
age=sys.argv[2]
print "Name "+name+"\nAge "+age
############
```

Would like to know why interactive way is not working as expected and what may be fix.

Comment: Code tags man...code tags!

Comment: You can [edit] yourself.

Comment: You would not happen to run the `ssh` command from a loop which you are not showing us, would you? Another thing to investigate is your SSH configuration. As it is, this is not reproducible, and in any event, apparently unrelated to your Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a regular terminal, the raw_input prompt is flushed immediately, meaning you will see the prompt "Enter Your Name".

If you run this script through ssh, it saves the output until the script it finished and only then prints everything in the buffer.

What you need is to run python unbuffered, which will force stdout to flush after every output, and thus display to your ssh session. This can be accomplished several ways.

```
ssh user@remotehost python -u script.py
```

or make the file executable *and* unbuffered by adding the following to top of your .py script. Be sure to use your actual python path here:

```
#! /usr/bin/python - u
```

and then in make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x script.py
```

then

```
ssh user@remotehost ./script.py
```

Comment: Problem is: `raw_input()` flushes the buffer after writing the prompt

Comment: Excellent point. I updated to clarify. Buffering would not occur if he ssh'd then called python, but it does if it's called in the same line.